# Google Chrome Theme

Tags: google-chrome, themes

I recently changed my google chrome theme but I don't like it and now it won't change back. I tried going into settings and going back to the default theme but even that didn't work. This theme literally won't go away and it's driving me insane. Any ideas???

Comment: Have you reloaded (aka fully restarted) chrome since the revert to default (or whatever was used previously)?

Answer (score 0):

Check if chrome still running, through task manager check for chrome.exe if it does exist end task.  then run chrome again. if it doesn't work

You could try to remove the theme extension from chrome folder
On windows >= 7  it should be C:\Users[USERNAME]\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions

There you can search for theme.  the theme should have images in it you can tell.  once you find it, move the folder to somewhere else. don't delete in case it is the wrong one.

Try this after closing chrome totally.